# Analyst estimates for an insurance company

Tags: stock-analysis, yahoo-finance

At this link: http://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/ae?s=MFC.TO 
under Analyst Estimates, under Growth Est,they have these numbers:
Current Qtr:
MFC:18.50%
Industry: 146.70%
Sector: 36.90%

Also how come these numbers are so out of sync with each other? Manulife is a leader in the insurance industry so how can it lag so far behind? Also how can insurance industry jump so far ahead of the financial sector?

Comment: **Small** companies can grow by leaps and bounds but **large** companies that already have large market share can't do so as easily.  For a small company with $1M revenue to find another $1M or $2M, not hard.  For $1B revenues to find another $1B, much harder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to consider is how broad is Yahoo! Finance taking in their data for making some comparisons.  For example, did you look at the other companies in the same industry?  On the [Industry page](http://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/in?s=MFC.TO), the Top Life Insurance Companies by Market Cap are mostly British companies which could make things a bit different than you'd think.

Another point is how this is just for one quarter which may be an anomaly as the data could get a bit awkward if some companies are just coming back to being profitable and could have what appears to be great growth but this is because their earnings grow from $.01/share to $1/share which is a growth of $10,000 percent as this is an increase of 100 times but really this may just be from various accounting charges the company had that hit its reserves and caused its earnings to dip temporarily.